# JSF Primefaces reload issue, could this be CSS issue or any other?

Tags: css, jsf-2, primefaces

In our web project we use JSF Myfaces, Primefaces 3.5. We have created our own primefaces theme for the project.

I find the following odd problems, which I suspect are due the css/library etc,

- Multiple selection checkbox on p:dataTable works on odd tries. I.e on the first load of the page the selection works. If I visit one other page and comeback, the select check box doesn't work. If I visit one more page and comeback it works again. When it doesn't work, if I do a page reload from browser it works again. (the problem is the same in all browsers)
- p:ajaxStatus onstart js function fires only for the first ajax call. For all subsequent calls this event is not fired. If I reload the page it again fires for the first ajax call and stops. We have not set any global setting on any ajax calls, I presume all calls default to global = true (the problem is the same in all browsers)
- for a p:barChart on chrome, the x and y-axis labels fall in to the axis, but when I reload the page the display is adjusted and correct (as it appears in firefox), and no further reload is need during the session, even when navigate back and forth from other pages.

Our application has a menu area on the top and ouputPanel that is updated using ui:include based on the ajax menu selection.

### I am not sure what could be causing these issues, and why things seem to work fine on reload. Where could the problem be?

The view code for the first issue related to the multiple selection checkbox is below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"           "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">
<h:head>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form id="dataForm">
        <p:messages id="tableMsgs" />
        <h:panelGroup>
            <p:dataTable value="#{usersBean.userDataModel}" var="user"
                id="userDataModel" rows="20" paginator="true"
                paginatorAlwaysVisible="false" editable="true"
                selection="#{usersBean.selectedUsers}"
                resizableColumns="false">

                <f:facet name="header">
                    <p:commandButton value="Flag User" process="@form"
                        action="#{usersBean.flagUser}"
                        icon="ui-icon-custom-arrow" iconPos="right"
                        update=":dataForm:tableMsgs"></p:commandButton>
                    <p:spacer width="10"></p:spacer>
                    <p:commandButton value="Delete User" process="@form"
                        icon="ui-icon-custom-arrow" iconPos="right" update="@form"
                        action="#{usersBean.deleteUser}">
                    </p:commandButton>
                </f:facet>

                <p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{usersBean.onEdit}"
                    oncomplete="resetCSS()"
                    update=":dataForm:tableMsgs />
                <p:ajax event="rowEditCancel" oncomplete="resetCSS()" />

                <p:column selectionMode="multiple" style="width:15px;" />
                <p:column headerText="Department" sortBy="#{user.dept.name}"
                    style="white-space:pre-line;width:100px">
                    <h:outputText value="#{user.dept.name}"
                        style="white-space:pre-line;width:100px;display:block;">
                    </h:outputText>
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="UserName" sortBy="#{user.userLoginName}"
                    style="width:100px;">
                    <h:outputText value="#{user.userLoginName}"
                        style="width:100px;display:block;"></h:outputText>
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Role" sortBy="#{user.role}"
                    style="width:100px;">
                    <p:cellEditor>
                        <f:facet name="output">
                            <h:outputText value="#{user.role}"
                                style="width:100px;display:block;"></h:outputText>
                        </f:facet>
                        <f:facet name="input">
                            <p:selectOneMenu value="#{user.role}" style="width:95px" rendered="#{user.enabled eq true}" >
                                <f:selectItems
                                    value="#{usersBean.rolesMap[user.dept.deptId]}"
                                    var="role" itemLabel="#{role}" itemValue="#{role}"></f:selectItems>
                            </p:selectOneMenu>
                            <h:outputText value="#{user.role}" rendered="#{user.enabled eq false}"/>
                        </f:facet>
                    </p:cellEditor>
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Manager" style="width:100px;">
                    <p:cellEditor>
                        <f:facet name="output">
                            <h:outputText
                                value="#{user.usermanagerByUserId.userByManagerId.userLoginName}"
                                style="width:100px;display:block;"></h:outputText>
                        </f:facet>
                        <f:facet name="input">
                            <p:selectOneMenu rendered="#{user.enabled eq true}" 
                                value="#{usersBean.managerIdMap[user.userId]}"
                                style="width:95px;">
                                <f:selectItems
                                    value="#{usersBean.managerMap[user.dept.deptId]}"
                                    var="manager" itemLabel="#{manager.userLoginName}"
                                    itemValue="#{manager.userId}"></f:selectItems>
                            </p:selectOneMenu>
                            <h:outputText
                                value="#{user.usermanagerByUserId.userByManagerId.userLoginName}" rendered="#{user.enabled eq false}"/>
                        </f:facet>
                    </p:cellEditor>
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Email" style="width:100px;">
                    <p:cellEditor>
                        <f:facet name="output">
                            <h:outputText value="#{user.email}"
                                style="width:100px;display:block;"></h:outputText>
                        </f:facet>
                        <f:facet name="input">
                            <p:inputText value="#{user.email}" style="width:95px;"
                                validatorMessage="Enter Valid Email" maxlength="100">
                                <f:validateRegex
                                    pattern="^[_A-Za-z0-9-\+]+(\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$" />
                            </p:inputText>
                        </f:facet>
                    </p:cellEditor>

                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Last Login" style="width:60px;">
                    <h:outputText value="#{user.lastLogin}"
                        style="width:60px;display:block;">
                        <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/yyyy"></f:convertDateTime>
                    </h:outputText>
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Status" style="width:40px;">
                    <p:cellEditor>
                        <f:facet name="output">
                            <h:outputText value="Enable" rendered="#{user.enabled eq true}"></h:outputText>
                            <h:outputText value="Disable"
                                rendered="#{user.enabled eq false}"></h:outputText>
                        </f:facet>
                        <f:facet name="input">
                            <p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{user.enabled}" />
                        </f:facet>
                    </p:cellEditor>
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Locked" style="width:40px;">
                    <p:cellEditor>
                        <f:facet name="output">
                            <h:outputText value="Locked" rendered="#{user.locked eq true}"
                                style="width:40px;display:block;" />
                            <h:outputText value="UnLocked" style="width:40px;display:block;"
                                rendered="#{user.locked eq false}"></h:outputText>
                        </f:facet>
                        <f:facet name="input">
                            <p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{user.locked}" />
                        </f:facet>
                    </p:cellEditor>
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Edit" style="width:30px;">
                    <p:rowEditor>
                    </p:rowEditor>
                </p:column>
            </p:dataTable>

        </h:panelGroup>
    </h:form>
</div>
```

Comment: Right, I was just hoping to get a quick solutions. We are trying things out and just found that setting global=true on the top p:menuItems has solved the p:ajaxStatus issue. I was able to get oer the barChart issue by explicitly setting jqPlot options. But the first item on the list, of selectManyCheckBox, is very difficult to understand and find a way out.I am very badly stuck on that.

Comment: I guess you're using Ajax?

Comment: Can you post the relevant code for your checkboxes? I'm guessing you're mixing up phases.

Comment: I have added the code to the question above.